Благодаря кому/чему - запятая?
Требуется ли постановка запятой в данном месте? В скобках.

Относительно новая модель шуруповёрта. Благодаря демократичной цене, высокой надёжности и удобству в обращении(,) пользуется большой популярностью у покупателей.


Пунктуация при оборотах с непервообразными предлогами

Благодаря демократичной цене, высокой надёжности и удобству в обращении пользуется большой популярностью у покупателей.
